# Как заменить символы только в первой половине строки?

Tags: c++, строки

Решаю задачку, не понимаю как сделать замену только в первой половине строки.

> Задача:
>   В заданной строке в первой половине строки все точки заменить символом `~`.

Сделал только замену:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char stroka[] = ".....";

    std::cout << stroka << "\n";

    for(int i = 0; stroka[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if(stroka[i] == '.')
            stroka[i] = '~';
    }

    std::cout << stroka << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема итерироваться только до половины строки?

Comment: Вместо `stroka[i] != '\0'` сделайте `i < длина строки`. Потом поделите длину на 2 и проблема решена.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте для начала пойдем "сложным путем". Очень сложным.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char stroka[] = ".....";

    std::cout << stroka << "\n";
    int len = sizeof(stroka);
    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; ++i)
    {
        if(stroka[i] == '.')
            stroka[i] = '~';
    }

    std::cout << stroka << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Но только у нас же с++!, поэтому, хотя бы так.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string stroka = ".....";

    std::cout << stroka << "\n";
    int len = stroka.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; ++i)
    {
        if(stroka[i] == '.')
            stroka[i] = '~';
    }

    std::cout << stroka << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Правда нужно подумать, что такое половина строки, если кол-во символов нечетно.

Comment: Но только у нас же с++!,  Можно одной строкой решить..

Comment: Ну не нужно говорить, что у Вашего решения одна строка. 3-4 строки на одну (смотря как считать). И я думаю, что Ваше решение хотя и хорошее, но вряд ли подойдет для решения школьного задания.

Comment: ну раз для школьного задания, тогда и не нужно было показывать решение с  std::string, а если уж воспользоваться им, то  и  воспользоваться нужно его услугами  например так, как я сейчас добавлю в ответ

Comment: думаю, что std::string - это самое правильное для школьного задания (если только преподаватель не рассказыват си через с++)

Comment: я не знаю что преподают в школах. Когда я  учился в школе, тогда не было персональных компьютеров, и в обычных школах не проходили ВТ.  А в таких школах как моя (физ.мат), только обьясняли что такое биты и байты , битовые операции , а компьютер Наири 2 занимал своими габаритами целый класс. Так что я не в курсе изучают ли нынче в школах STL контейнеры?...

Comment: я не знаю, но думаю что нет, потому что кто им преподает? те, кому лет 40. А они как раз и не учили stl

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...

std::replace(stroka, stroka + strlen(stroka)/2, '.', '~');
```

//вариант второй

```
std::string stroka("..........");
size_t hf = stroka.length() / 2;
cout << stroka.replace(0, hf, hf,  '~' );
```

Comment: Во втором варианте вы заменяете любые символы (а не только точки) в половине строки на `~`. Напишите это явно в ответе

Comment: @avp, вы правы, но я явно и написал, что в строке только точки  std::string stroka(".........."); Так что там нет других вариантов и условие является ли символ точкой, всегда выдаст истину

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без предварительного вычисления длины си-строки:

```
#include <iostream>


void replace_before_middle(char * begin)
{
    char const * last = begin;
    while (*last && *++last) {
        if (*begin == '.') {
            *begin = '~';
        }
        ++begin;
        ++last;
    }
}


int main()
{
    char str[] = ".+...";
    replace_before_middle(str);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Предлагаете читателям ощутить радость открытия? (со связным списком (например, его делением пополам) оно поначалу еще ошеломительней)

Comment: @avp не понял к чему это. Код же не сложный, банально один указатель "скачет" в два раза быстрее другого.

Comment: А вы по количеству плюсиков сможете оценить догадливость среднего коня сферического...

Answer (score 0):

Предложу и я свой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char stroka[] = ".....";

    std::cout << stroka << "\n";

    stroka[0] = '~';
    stroka[1] = '~';

    std::cout << stroka << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```